# Access object property values in an array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

I have an array containing objects that looks like this:

```
var persArr = [
         {name: "Adam", age: 37}, 
         {name: "Ben", age: 36}, 
         {name: "Chris", age: 46}
       ];
```

What I would like to do is create a string variable which takes the given names in each object in the array and puts them together like this:

```
var str = "Adam, Ben, Chris";
```

Any suggestions as to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
var str = persArr.map(function (pers) {
    return pers.name;
}).join(", ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
var names = [];
for (var k in persArr) {
  names.push(persArr[k].name);
}

var str = names.join(', ');
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
       var persArr = [{name: "Adam", age: 37}, {name: "Ben", age: 36}, {name: "Chris", age: 46}];
       var ar_length = persArr.length;
       var temp_arr = [];
       for(var i= 0;i<ar_length;i++){
            temp_arr.push(persArr[i].name);
       }
       alert(temp_arr.join(','));
```