# How do I get a key value of each object in a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

If I have an object in JS like the example below:

```
var files = [
  {
    "name":"test.png",
    "type":"image/png",
    "size":3536
  },
  {
    "name":"test.png",
    "type":"image/png",
    "size":3536
  },
  {
    "name":"test.png",
    "type":"image/png",
    "size":3536
  }
];
```

What is the most efficient way to list the name of each object?

Comment: Some libs provide a `pluck(files, "name")` functionality for this

Comment: function pluck(x) { return x[this]; }; var names = files.map(pluck, "name"), types=files.map(pluck, "type");

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/q/20067386/218196, or any of these http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+access+object+property+array . Feel free to reopen and close with a more appropriate duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    console.log(files[i].name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most efficient, but the shortest and most readable (IMO):

```
var names = files.map(function (file) { return file.name; });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0,l=files.length;i<l;i++) {
    console.log(files[i].name);
}
```

Comment: Why the unnecessary extra variable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349425/whats-the-fastest-way-to-loop-through-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: If you actually look at the test data provided in the very question you linked to you can see that in modern browsers this isn't the fastest solution. Even so, this is another example of premature optimization.

Comment: The cached length on chrome v36 seems to be contradictory to your comment.   https://blogs.oracle.com/greimer/resource/loop-test.html

Comment: Read the jsperf linked in the same question you linked. There's a substantial amount of different samples from different systems (as opposed to your single test) and practically all show that the `while` solution is the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

A simple for-loop should work best:

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    console.log(files[i].name);
}
```

---

To do the above as a key-value, you would create an object instead of an array:

```
var files = {
    "test1.png":
    {
        "type":"image/png",
        "size":3536
    },
    "test2.png":
    {
        "type":"image/png",
        "size":3536
    },
    "test3.png":
    {
        "type":"image/png",
        "size":3536
    }
};
```

Then you would iterate through them like this:

```
for (var key in files) {
    console.log("File name: " + key);
    console.log("File data: " + files[key]);
}
```